# Starting Big Project With Test Driven Development

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, spring-mvc, tdd, domain-driven-design

I have a model for my project like that shown in the following diagram. I planned the project using Domain Driven Design and development style is Test Driven Development. And layers are as following.

[image]

The project is an MVC based web project. So far, I write tests for started projects before. I have not started a new Project with TDD. So I do not know where I start to write tests. Which layer should be developed first? Where should I start?

Is there anyone developed enterprise projects, can share his/her thoughts and experience?

Answer (score 6):

It is always tricky to get a project off the ground using TDD if you have never done it before, and it is too big a topic to discuss in a Stack Overflow answer.

The best I can recommend is to read [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627) - in this book you are taken step by step through getting an application off the ground using TDD, and examples of how you would solve different problems using TDD as the application grows. The application they use as an example in the book is realistic and should help you learn the skills required to get yourself off the ground.

Comment: One think the book mentions is the [Walking Skeleton](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Walking+skeleton), something that might help you get started.

Comment: Hi @bookmarker - did this answer help you, and if so would you be able to accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's your testing strategy? Does your T in TDD represent unit-testing only?

If it is, I usually start with the a very small piece of User interface or application layer(small steps, only implement the key part of a html form or anything could wire the data flow as simple as possible), they are tightly coupled with your use case/story. Build a skeleton covering all layers using mock/stubs. So when the procedure is done, I'll have some very simple controller/application services, simple domain models and some interfaces for infrastructure. Next, test and implement them until the manual user acceptance could be finished. Then repeat the two steps.

I agree with robjohcox if you want to be driven by acceptance tests, "it is too big a topic to discuss in a Stack Overflow answer."

Comment: Agreed. The start-start could be the smallest possible GUI feature you plan to implement. From there, dive down into just enough controller to exercise one feature of it, mocking and stubbing as you go. But Freeman's book is definitely a better resource than we could provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't start your new project or you just created your project but haven't write much code in it, I would suggest you delete the current one and recreate a new MVC project. But this time remember to tick the box. That way, you will see a new test project created for you with a Test class inside.

This is a good way for you to start.

[image]

Comment: I know all of that creating projects, Which Project layer should begin coding.

Comment: @youtubeline, you'd begin with the user stories, which should be driven through the GUI.  Therefore you'd start with the View layer.